# Gradient layer not in the right place

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cagradientlayer

I have the following code as follows:

```
playView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
let gradient1 = CAGradientLayer()
gradient1.frame = playView.frame
gradient1.cornerRadius = 16
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // set P3 colour
} else {
    // set sRGB colour
}
gradient1.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient1.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
playView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient1, at: 0)
```

On the 3rd line of the block of code above, I set the frame of the gradient equal to the frame I want it to fill.

When I run the app on different devices, the gradient layer will only fill the correct area if the device the app is being run on is the one selected in the Interface Builder.

I currently have the code in viewDidLoad(), and so the issue can be solved by moving the code to viewDidAppear(), but then when the app is loaded, there will be a slight delay before the gradient appears, not giving a smooth look and feel.

Is there another method I can put the code in, so that the gradient shows in the correct place, whilst at the same time being there as soon as the user sees the screen? Or alternatively, a way to make the gradient fill the view, whilst still keeping the code in viewDidLoad()?

EDIT: viewWillAppear() does not work, nor does viewWillLayoutSubviews(). Surely there must be away to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can put inside this block:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages of putting the code here compared to putting the code in viewWillAppear()

Comment: This method is called ever time when your frame update. In your case doesn't have a big disavantage.

Comment: @D-AUK add color in your gradient, here work fine your code in viewDidLoad

        gradient1.colors = [UIColor.black, UIColor.blue]

Answer (score 0):

viewDidAppear() works. This screen is the root controller - I don't know if that makes a difference or not, but there is no visible delay on applying the gradient backgrounds.

I would be interested if anyone could explain this? I have a bar chart in another part of the app and in viewDidAppear() there is code to complete the bar chart, however there is a delay in it being filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Change the layer.frame property inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` 
method. This is to make sure that the subview (playView) has already a proper frame.